# numerical integration of a tricky function

Tags: r, numerical-integration

The `prob` package numerically evaluates characteristic functions for base R distributions. For almost all distributions there are existing formulas.  For a few cases, though, no closed-form solution is known.  Case in point: the Weibull distribution (but see below).

For the Weibull characteristic function I essentially compute two integrals and put them together:

```
fr <- function(x) cos(t * x) * dweibull(x, shape, scale)
fi <- function(x) sin(t * x) * dweibull(x, shape, scale)
Rp <- integrate(fr, lower = 0, upper = Inf)$value
Ip <- integrate(fi, lower = 0, upper = Inf)$value
Rp + (0+1i) * Ip
```

Yes, it's clumsy, but it works surprisingly well!     ...*ahem*, most of the time.  A user reported recently that the following breaks:

```
cfweibull(56, shape = 0.5, scale = 1)

Error in integrate(fr, lower = 0, upper = Inf) : 
  the integral is probably divergent
```

Now, we know that the integral isn't divergent, so it must be a numerical problem. With some fiddling I could get the following to work:

```
fr <- function(x) cos(56 * x) * dweibull(x, 0.5, 1)

integrate(fr, lower = 0.00001, upper = Inf, subdivisions=1e7)$value
[1] 0.08024055
```

That's OK, but it isn't quite right, plus it takes a fair bit of fiddling which doesn't scale well.  I've been investigating this for a better solution.  I found a recently published "closed-form" for the characteristic function with `scale > 1` ([see here](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10687-012-0151-4)), but it involves [Wright's generalized confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) which isn't implemented in R (yet).  I looked into the archives for `integrate` alternatives, and there's a ton of stuff out there which doesn't seem very well organized.

As part of that searching it occurred to me to translate the region of integration to a finite interval via the inverse tangent, and *voila*!  Check it out:

```
cfweibull3 <- function (t, shape, scale = 1){
  if (shape <= 0 || scale <= 0) 
    stop("shape and scale must be positive")
  fr <- function(x) cos(t * tan(x)) * dweibull(tan(x), shape, scale)/(cos(x))^2
  fi <- function(x) sin(t * tan(x)) * dweibull(tan(x), shape, scale)/(cos(x))^2
  Rp <- integrate(fr, lower = 0, upper = pi/2, stop.on.error = FALSE)$value
  Ip <- integrate(fi, lower = 0, upper = pi/2, stop.on.error = FALSE)$value
  Rp + (0+1i) * Ip
}

> cfweibull3(56, shape=0.5, scale = 1)
[1] 0.08297194+0.07528834i
```

### Questions:

1. Can you do better than this?
2. Is there something about numerical integration routines that people who are expert about such things could shed some light on what's happening here? I have a sneaking suspicion that for large `t` the cosine fluctuates rapidly which causes problems...?
3. Are there existing R routines/packages which are better suited for this type of problem, and could somebody point me to a well-placed position (on the mountain) to start the climb?

### Comments:

1. Yes, it is bad practice to use `t` as a function argument.
2. I calculated the exact answer for `shape > 1` using the published result with Maple, and the `brute-force-integrate-by-the-definition-with-R` kicked Maple's ass.  That is, I get the same answer (up to numerical precision) in a small fraction of a second and an even smaller fraction of the price.

### Edit:

I was going to write down the exact integrals I'm looking for but it seems this particular site doesn't support MathJAX so I'll give links instead.  I'm looking to numerically evaluate the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) of the [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) for reasonable inputs `t` (whatever that means).  The value is a complex number but we can split it into its real and imaginary parts and that's what I was calling `Rp` and `Ip` above.

One final comment: Wikipedia has a formula listed (an infinite series) for the Weibull c.f. and that formula matches the one proved in the paper I referenced above, **however**, that series has only been proved to hold for `shape > 1`.  The case `0 < shape < 1` is still an open problem; see the paper for details.

Comment: To address your question about numerical integration: have you experimented with changing the default interval setting? `?integrate... integrate(f, lower, upper, ..., subdivisions=100,
          rel.tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25, abs.tol = rel.tol,
          stop.on.error = TRUE, keep.xy = FALSE, aux = NULL) ` . So what happens if you increase to `subdivisions = 1e4` , for example?

Comment: @Carl, yes, that's one of the things I fiddled with, and that gives an answer sometimes (e.g. the first stanza with `subdivisions = 1e7`). I'd like to avoid the fiddling if possible, but maybe it's not possible. If it's not possible because `dweibull` is tricky, that's OK, but I don't want it to be because of ignorance on my part w.r.t. numerical integration methods (in R).

Comment: I have found that some integration techniques struggle with Exp[-1/t^2] (between say -1 and 1) which is not difficult unless you assume there is a polynomial representation.  What I would suggest is that rather than trying to subdivide integration regions by their analytic error which leads to an infinte subdivision when the funtion is not possible to represent by a polynomial, sort the regions by their error and subdivide the most (largest errors) regoins first till you get the desired degree of accuracy

Comment: @aronp Thanks - that's a very insightful comment.  I like that and will look into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be interested to look at this paper, which discuss different integration methods for highly oscillating integrals -- that's what you are essentially trying to compute:
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.8.6944

Also, another possible advice, is that instead of infinite limit you may want to specify a smaller one, because if you specify the precision that you want, then  based on the cdf of the weibull you can easily estimate how much of the tail you can truncate. And if you have a fixed limit, then you can specify exactly (or almost) the number of subdivisions (e.g. in order to have a few(4-8) points per period).

Comment: Thanks - this is just the sort of thing I was looking for (+1).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem than Jay - not with the Weibull distribution but with the *integrate* function. I found my answer to **Jay's question 3** in a comment to this question:

[Divergent Integral in R is solvable in Wolfram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713582/divergent-integral-in-r-is-solvable-in-wolfram)

The R package *pracma* contains several functions for solving integrals numerically. In the package, one finds some R functions for integrating certain mathematical functions. And there is a more general function *integral*. That helped in my case. Example code is given below.

**To questions 2:** The first answer to the linked question (above) states that not the complete error message of the C source file is printed out by R (The function may just converge too slowly). Therefore, I would agree with Jay that the fast fluctuation of the cosine may be a problem. In my case and in the example below it was the problem.

**Example Code**

```
# load Practical Numerical Math Functions package
library(pracma)

# define function
testfun <- function(r) cos(r*10^6)*exp(-r)

# Integrate it numerically with the basic 'integrate'.
out1 = integarte(testfun, 0, 100)
# "Error in integrate(testfun, 0, 100) : the integral is probably divergent"

# Integrate it numerically with 'integral' from 'pracma' package
# using 'Gauss-Kronrod' method and 10^-8 as relative tolerance. I
# did not try the other ones.
out2 = integral(testfun, 0, 100, method = 'Kronrod', reltol = 1e-8)
```

**Two remarks**

1. The *integral* function does not break as the *integrate* function does but it may take quite a long time to run. I do not know (and I did not try) whether the user can limit the number of iterations (?).
2. Even if the *integral* function finalises without errors I am not sure how *correct* the result is. Numerically integrating a function which is *fast* fluctuating around zero seems to be quite tricky since one does not know where exactly values on the fluctuating function are calculated *(twice as much positive than negative values; positive values close to local maxima and negative values far off)*. I am not on expert on numeric integration but I just got to know some basic fixed-step integration methods in my numerics lectures. So maybe the adaptive methods used in *integral* deal with this problem in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm attempting to answer questions 1 & 3. That being said I am not contributing any original code. I did a google search and hopefully this is helpful. Good luck!

Source:http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf (p.6)

```
#Script

library(ggplot2)

## sampling from a Weibull distribution with parameters shape=2.1 and scale=1.1
x.wei<-rweibull(n=200,shape=2.1,scale=1.1) 

#Weibull population with known paramters shape=2 e scale=1
x.teo<-rweibull(n=200,shape=2, scale=1) ## theorical quantiles from a

#Figure
qqplot(x.teo,x.wei,main="QQ-plot distr. Weibull") ## QQ-plot
abline(0,1) ## a 45-degree reference line is plotted
```

Comment: Tyler, thanks for giving a stab at it and for the well wishes.  I am afraid I can't give this answer an upvote because it isn't actually related to the question I was asking.  I'm going to edit the question to spell out the exact number I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is this of any use?

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378383907000452

Muraleedharana et al (2007) Modified Weibull distribution for maximum and significant wave height simulation and prediction, *Coastal Engineering*, Volume 54, Issue 8, August 2007, Pages 630–638

From the abstract: "The characteristic function of the Weibull distribution is derived."

Comment: Glen, thanks, actually it's interesting, if you dig a little deeper the authors of that paper claimed they'd found the c.f., but in a series of back-and-forth Letters to the editor, Nadarajah demonstrated that Muraleedharana et al. were wrong.  It was Nadarajah and Kotz that gave the correct form of the MGF around the same time and Nadarajah (with some other fellow) who recently published the "closed form" I was talking about above.