# Unsmooth lines when using the dnorm and plot functions in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution, data-visualization

I have some troubles when I use the `dnorm` and `plot` functions in R.  When I execute the following code in Rcommander:

```
> x <- 50:225
> 
> a< - dnorm(x,165,15); b <- dnorm(x,149,18); c <- dnorm(x,134,25)
> 
> plot(x, a, type="l", lwd=3, ylim=c(0,1.2*max(a,b,c)), ylab="Probability
>      Density", xlab="Perikymata") lines(x,b, type="l", lwd=3, col="Red")
>      lines(x,c, type="l", lwd=3, col="Blue")
```

I get the next image:

[image]

For now, perfect. The problem arrives when I change these values, for example, using the following code:

```
> x <- 0:15
> 
> a <- dnorm(x,5.28,0.91); b <- dnorm(x,8.45,1.36)
> 
> plot(x,a, type="l", lwd=3, ylim=c(0,1.2*max(a,b)), ylab="Probability
>      Density", xlab="Perikymata") lines(x,b, type="l", lwd=3, col="Red")
```

Using this text I get the next image:

[image]

How can I do to smooth these two lines in the last graph, taking as comparison the first image, and doing the two lines to resemble to normal distributions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R is calculating Y values ("Probability Density") only at certain increments in X ("Perikymata").  In the original plot, your X values ranged from 50 to 225, i.e., 175 units of Perikymata.  In your new plot, the X values only range from 0 to 15, i.e., 15 units of Perikymata.  You can get a smoother plot by ensuring that there are more Y values calculated.  For example, instead of 15, you could get 175.  You can do that by using:

```
x <- seq(from=0, to=15, length.out=175)
```

Comment: And now other question. How can I calculate the overlapping area of both normal distributions?

Comment: You're welcome, @antecessor. If this has resolved your issue, you may want to accept it by clicking the check mark below the vote total to its left. Since you are new here, you may want to take our [tour](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains information for new users.

Comment: That may be best asked as a new question, since it isn't directly related to this. In addition, the overlapping area in what sense exactly? Do you want to know the proportion of the black area under the black curve, the red area under the red curve, or to integrate over the overlapping region? In addition, are you asking about the ideas or for the R code?

Comment: Integrate over the overlapping region.

Comment: That question is probably on-topic on math.SE. In practice, you would probably solve the integral numerically. How to do it w/ R could probably be asked on SO, but you will need to show some kind of effort at solving it in the question; people frown on straight requests for code.

Comment: A place to start might be something like this: [Numerical integration of a tricky function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12433609/1217536).

Comment: something like `integrate(function(x) min(dnorm(x,mu1,s1),dnorm(x,mu2,s2)), lower=-Inf, upper=Inf)`