# Integral of dnorm(x, mean=200, sd=20) is not 1

Tags: r, integral, probability-density

I tried to calculate the integral of the density of the normal distribution with expected value 200 and standard deviation 20. From -Inf to Inf this should be 1.

I get the following:

```
> integrate(dnorm, mean=200, sd=20,-Inf, Inf)$value
[1] 1.429508e-08
```

For expected values below 169 I get the right value, 1. 
How can I get the right value for bigger expected values?

Comment: Why are you integrating the normal density function when R offers the CDF, i.e., `pnorm`?

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively

```
integrate(dnorm, mean=200, sd=20, lower= -Inf, upper= Inf, abs.tol = 0)$value
[1] 1
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023899/integrate-in-r-gives-terribly-wrong-answer).

And to see what is going on, note the number of subdivisions in the following:

```
js <- integrate(dnorm, mean=200, sd=20, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf)
as <- integrate(dnorm, mean=200, sd=20, lower = -1e4, upper = 1e4)
cj <- integrate(dnorm, mean=200, sd=20, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf, abs.tol = 0)

str(js)
List of 5
 $ value       : num 1.43e-08
 $ abs.error   : num 2.77e-08
 $ subdivisions: int 2
 $ message     : chr "OK"
 $ call        : language integrate(f = dnorm, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf, mean = 200, sd = 20)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "integrate"

str(as)
List of 5
 $ value       : num 1
 $ abs.error   : num 2e-07
 $ subdivisions: int 9
 $ message     : chr "OK"
 $ call        : language integrate(f = dnorm, lower = -10000, upper = 10000, mean = 200,      sd = 20)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "integrate"

str(cj)
List of 5
 $ value       : num 1
 $ abs.error   : num 9.37e-05
 $ subdivisions: int 12
 $ message     : chr "OK"
 $ call        : language integrate(f = dnorm, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf, mean = 200, sd = 20,      abs.tol = 0)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "integrate"
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting the interval finite seems to help

```
integrate(dnorm, mean=200, sd=20, -1e4, 1e4)
# 1 with absolute error < 2e-07
```