# integrate() gives totally wrong number

Tags: r

integrate() gives horribly wrong answer:

```
integrate(function (x) dnorm(x, -5, 0.07), -Inf, Inf, subdivisions = 10000L)
# 2.127372e-23 with absolute error < 3.8e-23
```

The return value should obviously be 1 (normal distrubution integrates to 1), but integrate() returns ridiculously small number, with wrong error reporting, and no warning...

Any ideas?

This seems the default `integrate()` is horribly buggy... and I just found this by chance! Is there any **reliable** R package to compute numerical integration?

**EDIT:** I tried package `pracma` and I see the same problem! :

```
require(pracma)
integral(function (x) dnorm(x, -5, 0.07), -Inf, Inf)
# For infinite domains Gauss integration is applied!
# [1] 0
```

**EDIT:** Hmm... digging deeper, it seems that he has trouble to find the very narrow domain for the function which is numerically > 0. When I set the limits  to certain (very close to 0, 1) quantiles, it starts to work:

```
integral(function (x) dnorm(x, -5, 0.07), qnorm(1e-10, -5, 0.07), qnorm(1 - 1e-10, -5, 0.07))
```

But anyway, this is quite horrible gotcha... wonder if there is any remedy for this.

Comment: This is chaotic in a sense, since `dnorm(x, -5.5, 0.07)` is "1" but `-6` is again quite small. If you look at the `x` values tested (perhaps add a `message(paste(x, collapse="\n"))` before `dnorm`), it might provide some insight into its *estimation*.

Answer (score 13):

From the online documentation:  "Like all numerical integration routines, these evaluate the function on a finite set of points. If the function is approximately constant (in particular, zero) over nearly all its range it is possible that the result and error estimate may be seriously wrong."

I take this to mean "caveat emptor".  I notice that in your example, the absolute error is greater than value of the integral.  Given that you know f(x) > 0 for all x, at least it's giving you the chance to spot that something has gone wrong.  It's down to you to take the opportunity.

```
integrate( function(x) dnorm(x, -5, 0.07), -20, 10, subdivisions=1000L)
```

Gives

```
1 with absolute error < 9.8e-07
```

The warning in the online doc says to me that, given your apparent definition of buggy, the answer to your question is "no, there is no reliable numerical intergration method.  Not in R or any other language".  No numerical integration technique should be used blindly.  The user needs to check their inputs are sensible and the output is reasonable.  It's no good believing an answer just because the computer gave it to you.

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023899/integrate-in-r-gives-terribly-wrong-answer?rq=1).

Answer (score 10):

Expanding a little further on @r2evan's and @Limey's comments:

@Limey: for *very general* problems like this, there is simply no way to guarantee a generic solution.

One way to solve such problem is to use more knowledge of the properties of the integrand (@r2evans's answer); the [answer referenced by @Limey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023899/integrate-in-r-gives-terribly-wrong-answer?rq=1) goes into detail for a different problem.

One "gotcha" that you may not have thought of is that trying out a bunch of generic methods, tuning settings, etc. may mislead you into concluding that some settings/methods are *generically* better than the first one you tried that failed to get the right answer. (Methods that work *may* work better because they're generically better, but trying them on one example doesn't prove it!)

As an example, the description of `pcubature()` (in `?cubature::pcubature` says

> This algorithm is often superior to h-adaptive integration for
>        smooth integrands in a few (<=3) dimensions, but is a poor choice
>        in higher dimensions or for non-smooth integrands.

However, recall that `pcubature()` happens to fail for your example, which is a smooth low-dimensional case - exactly where `pcubature()` is supposed to perform *better* - which suggests that it may be just luck that `hcubature()` works and `pcubature()` doesn't in this case.

An illustration of how sensitive the results can be to parameters (lower/upper limits in this case):

```
library(emdbook)
cc <- curve3d(integrate( dnorm, mean=-5, sd=0.07,
        lower=x, upper=y, subdivisions=1000L)$value,
       xlim=c(-30,-10), ylim=c(0,30), n = c(61, 61),
       sys3d="image", col=c("black", "white"),
    xlab="lower", ylab="upper")
```

White squares are successful (integral=1), black squares are bad (integral=0).

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Try package `cubature`.

```
library(cubature)

hcubature(function (x) dnorm(x, -5, 0.07), -Inf, Inf)
#$integral
#[1] 1
#
#$error
#[1] 9.963875e-06
#
#$functionEvaluations
#[1] 405
#
#$returnCode
#[1] 0
```

Note that function `pcubature` in the same package also returns 0.

From `vignette("cubature")`, section Introduction. My emphasis.

> This R `cubature` package exposes both the hcubature and pcubature
>   routines of the underlying C cubature library, including the
>   vectorized interfaces.
>
> Per the documentation, use of `pcubature` is advisable only for smooth
>   integrands in dimensions up to three at most. In fact, the `pcubature`
>   routines perform significantly worse than the vectorized `hcubature`
>   in inappropriate cases. **So when in doubt, you are better off using
>   `hcubature`.**

Since in this case the integrand is the normal density, a smooth and 1-dimensional function, there would be reasons to prefer `pcubature`. But it doesn't give the right result. The vignette concludes the following.

> 2. Vectorized `hcubature` seems to be a good starting point.
> 3. For smooth integrands in low dimensions (≤3),  `pcubature` might be worth trying out. Experiment before using in a production package.

Comment: Wow!! So there are packages which can deal with this, awesome! But do you know what is the difference between hcubature and pcubature then, and why the other returns 0? Just to know how much I can rely on this...

Comment: @TMS I have added a quote from the documentation. And a final note.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting workaround: not too surprisingly, `integrate` does well when the values sampled (on `(-Inf,Inf)`, no less) are closer to the "center" of the data. You can reduce this by using your function but hinting at a center:

Without adjustment:

```r
t(sapply(-10:10, function(i) integrate(function (x) dnorm(x, i, 0.07), -Inf, Inf, subdivisions = 10000L)))
#       value        abs.error    subdivisions message call      
#  [1,] 0            0            1            "OK"    Expression
#  [2,] 1            4.611403e-05 10           "OK"    Expression
#  [3,] 6.619713e-19 1.212066e-18 2            "OK"    Expression
#  [4,] 7.344551e-71 0            2            "OK"    Expression
#  [5,] 3.389557e-06 6.086176e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
#  [6,] 2.127372e-23 3.849798e-23 2            "OK"    Expression
#  [7,] 1            3.483439e-05 8            "OK"    Expression
#  [8,] 1            6.338078e-07 11           "OK"    Expression
#  [9,] 1            3.408389e-06 7            "OK"    Expression
# [10,] 1            6.414833e-07 8            "OK"    Expression
# [11,] 1            7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
# [12,] 1            6.414833e-07 8            "OK"    Expression
# [13,] 1            3.408389e-06 7            "OK"    Expression
# [14,] 1            6.338078e-07 11           "OK"    Expression
# [15,] 1            3.483439e-05 8            "OK"    Expression
# [16,] 2.127372e-23 3.849798e-23 2            "OK"    Expression
# [17,] 3.389557e-06 6.086176e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
# [18,] 7.344551e-71 0            2            "OK"    Expression
# [19,] 6.619713e-19 1.212066e-18 2            "OK"    Expression
# [20,] 1            4.611403e-05 10           "OK"    Expression
# [21,] 0            0            1            "OK"    Expression
```

If we add a "centering" hint, though, we get more consistent results:

```r
t(sapply(-10:10, function(i) integrate(function (x, offset) dnorm(x + offset, i, 0.07), -Inf, Inf, subdivisions = 10000L, offset = i)))
#       value abs.error    subdivisions message call      
#  [1,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
#  [2,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
#  [3,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
#  [4,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
#  [5,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
#  [6,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
#  [7,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
#  [8,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
#  [9,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
# [10,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
# [11,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
# [12,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
# [13,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
# [14,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
# [15,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
# [16,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
# [17,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
# [18,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
# [19,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
# [20,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
# [21,] 1     7.578907e-06 3            "OK"    Expression
```

I recognize this is mitigation for heuristics, presumes knowing something about your distribution before integration, and is not a perfect "generic" solution. Just offering another perspective.

Comment: Wow, this offset idea isn't bad! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I consider it an informed hack, compensating for imperfect heuristics. It would be much better to have more resilient heuristics to begin with.