# Integrating over different normal distributions are giving 0 probability

Tags: r

I'm trying to integrate over normal distribution for some numbers, but some inputs are giving weird results

```
> round(integrate(dnorm, mean=322.3037, sd=18.96672, lower= 86, upper= Inf,abs.tol = 0L)$value*100,0)
[1] 100
> round(integrate(dnorm, mean=322.3037, sd=18.96672, lower= 85, upper= Inf,abs.tol = 0L)$value*100,0)
[1] 0
```

Why the second result is giving 0, when should be giving 100 as the first one?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/62122505/3358272?

Comment: @r2evans.  It could well be.  Replacing `upper=Inf` with `upper=600` gives me the correct answer in both cases.